# Failed to parse input string "" - in BigQuery

Tags: parsing, time, google-bigquery

I have a timestamp column in below format

**3/31/2020 10:43:17.000 AM**

trying to parse it and convert to Date column but running into error

Using below conversion

```
date(parse_datetime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%E3S %p',datefield))
```

but running into error

Please note i'm using `%E3S` at seconds field as per this
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems because `datefield` column of your table has an empty string. remove them first or use `safe.` prefix like `safe.parse_datetime` so that it will return `null` rather than an exception in case of an empty string.

Comment: and you should use `%I` instead of `%H` for an hour format when a datetime string has a `AM` or `PM`.

Comment: when i use safe.parse_datetime and grouping by datefield it just giving me total count with datefield as null   ///


select count(*),date(safe.parse_datetime('%m/%d/%Y %%I:%M:%S%E3S %p',datefield)) as datefield from table group by datefield order by datefield desc;

My intension is to get count's  for each date

Comment: would you fix `%%I`  to `%I` in your query and try it again ?

Comment: date(safe.parse_datetime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%E3S %p',datefield))   fixed my issue

@Jaytiger Thank you for your help